# Creating a Nagios/Centreon standby server

Tags: nagios, centreon

I am in the process of creating a standby Nagios/Centreon server which will take over should our main server fail.

Presently we're replicating the primary centreon server MySQL databases to the standby server using MySQL replication. All of my logins etc on the failover server are identical to the primary server.

The standby server's `nagios`, `ndo2db`, `centstorage` and `centcore` daemons are disabled on the standby server.

In the event of a failure on the primary we'll (if possible and depending on how catastrophic the failure is) disable the aforementioned daemons and start them on the backup server.

My only stumbling block at the moment is

1. How to rebuild the graph RRD's? Is it simply a case of going to:

   `Administration -> Options -> CentStorage -> Manage`

   Then selecting all of the hosts and services then doing a `Rebuild RRD Databases` ?
2. Generating the configuration for Nagios - Is it just a case of exporting the config before starting Nagios?
3. Are there any other files or data that I should be concerned with copying across to the backup server periodically?
4. Are there any files on the backup server that should be deleted prior to failing over (lock files, logs etc, `nagios.log`, `retention.dat`, `service-perfdata`, `status.dat`, `status.sav`)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Never tested this, but it sounds correct.
2. Yes.
3. Your nagios/libexec (shouldn't change all that much) and nagios/etc (at least make a tar ball of this - though best to store these in an SCS) and nagios/var.
4. Yes, save those var files.  Else you'll be seeing a lot of red on the console when the DR machine comes on line.